# Display failed message and stop processing an order, payment, user - CSCART

Tags: php, cs-cart

Im trying to block order, payment, user creation process.
Is this possible using hooks, what is the correct method to stop the process after recieving a bad request from my custom api.

Answer (score 0):

You could install the provided catalog add-on and allow users to only create an account with your approval.